# The mechanics of this shell syntax: ${1:-$(</dev/stdin)}

Tags: bash, stdin, command-substitution, parameter-expansion

I recently came across this really neat syntax, in the context of creating `bash` functions which can accept an argument or a stream from STDIN (i.e. can be piped to). On the surface, I understand what's happening here, but I'd like a bit more explanation of the actual *mechanics* of how this is working.

Here's the syntax (as per the title): `${1:-$(</dev/stdin)}`

And in context, one might use it as:

```
log(){
 echo -e >&1 "INFO: ${1:-$(</dev/stdin)}"
}
```

Allowing the following usage:

```
$ log foo
INFO: foo
```

Alternatively, you could also do this

```
mv -v foo.ext bar.ext | log
INFO: renamed 'foo.ext' -> 'bar.ext'
```

This is great because its the single most concise method I've seen for enabling both argument and pipe functionality with `bash` functions (I forget where I came across it now, unfortunately).

Now, I understand (or think I understand), most of what's happening here at least superficially, but I'd appreciate a deeper understanding. Here's how I interpret it, followed by my remaining questions:

#### `${1:-$(</dev/stdin)}`

- `${1}` is obviously the default argument that a function accepts
- `${1:-x}` is a variable/brace expansion 'fall back' to the string `'x'` if `$1` is otherwise empty (or unset?). In this case falling back to the STDIN process sub.
- `$()` is obviously a <s>process</s> command substitution
- and finally, `</dev/stdin` is obviously a redirect from standard input which allows the pipe to work at all.

This essentially says if `$1` isn't populated by an argument, fall back to using STDIN - which I'm happy with conceptually.

So here are my questions:

1. I've never seen a redirect (`<`) inside a <s>process</s> command substitution, without an actual command preceding it (e.g. `$(cat < somefile.ext)`). So what is actually happening (the nitty-gritty) when the <s>process</s> command substitution receives the redirect with no other command to invoke?
2. Why is it necessary to wrap the STDIN redirect in a <s>process</s> command substitution at all? (actually, as I write this it occurs to me I haven't tested it without, but I'll keep it simple).
3. Is this *safe*? I've used it with multiline STDIN, and it hasn't broken so far. Where might this fall down (if anywhere?).

Comment: Cool use of parameter expansion. Personally I would create two functions. One for normal logging (`log`) and one for logging piped input (`log_pipe` or whatever).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `$(`..`)`: from bash manual is a command substitution not process substitution `<(`..`)`. and from [Command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution)

> The command substitution $(cat file) can be replaced by the equivalent but faster $(< file).

2. `/dev/stdin` is a symlink to `/proc/self/fd/0`, convenient here because of `$(<`..`)` syntax which expects a file.
3. this could cause a problem because the command may be blocked until stdin closed. it is safe in the meaning that multiline input will be preserved because au double-quotes.

Finally creating a pipe and forking a process (like in `mv -v foo.ext bar.ext | log`) for each log command may be inefficient.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I have a bad habit of referring to them both as the same thing... I'll edit.

Comment: ok, sorry for my first answer where i confused `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/tty`

Answer (score 2):

Answering your questions

- You have confused the syntax between using process substitution which takes the syntax of `<(cmd)` and simple shell re-direction `< file`. In plain form, `<` basically is to *read* from the standard input and `>` to *write* to standard output. The syntax `< file` is a short-hand syntax to put the contents of the `file` made available on the standard input which can be *read* by the commands.
- So when you run `cat < file`, it basically puts the content of the `file` in standard input file descriptor which is later than `read` by the `cat` process. The advantage of using `$(<file)` would be the shell doesn't have fork an external process `cat` and just use its own mechanism to read the file content.
- The `$(..)` is a syntax for command-substitution where command is run in a sub-shell environment and `$(..)` is replaced with the standard output of the command. For a special case of `"$(<file)"` i.e. without any commands and only re-directions involved, the shell instead of reading from the standard input starts reading from the *start* of the file and puts the result on the standard output.

Comment: Actually stdin could well be a pipe, not a terminal, right?

Comment: @Inian thanks for the answer. I mixed up the terminology of command vs process substitution, but I am clear on the difference between `< file`/ `> file` and `<(file)` and `$()`. I just hadn't come across `$(<file)` before.